# Random walk dynamics for coefficient bounded between -1 and 1

Tags: time-series, state-space-models

Suppose I have a linear state space model:

$y_t = \beta_tx_t + u_t \hspace{1cm} \mathcal{N(0,\sigma^2_u)}$

$\beta_t = \beta_{t-1} + \nu_t  \hspace{1cm} \mathcal{N(0,\sigma^2_\nu)}$

For some reason I know that $\beta_t$ is bounded between -1 and 1. Is there anything wrong with the specification of the random walk dynamics for $\beta_t$? In particular, since the variance of $\beta_t$ goes to infinity as $t$ goes to infinity, is the specification of the state space model in contrast with the fact that $\beta_t$ is bounded between -1 and 1?

Comment: Doesn’t look like ssm with time varying coefficient

Comment: Is a state space model with the coefficient in the observation equation time varying. call it as you want

Comment: you wont get an answer to your question with this attitude

Comment: Giorgetto, have you transposed $x$ and $\beta$ in the top equation? I think there's a pretty strong convention of coefficients first, variables second in linear model representations that I have seen.

Comment: @Aksakal sorry I didn't mean to be rude of course, I was just saying you could call it as you wish (I am not a native English speaker, maybe it sounded rude) .

Comment: @Alexis $\beta_t$ is a scalar in my setting (I have only one regressor)

Comment: @Giorgetto Is there some reason you are ignoring the convention of writing equations like your top one as $y_t = \beta_t x_t + u_t$?

Comment: @Alexis actually if $\beta_t$ is scalar you should be able to write it in both ways

Comment: @Giorgetto You could also write it as $1 = \frac{x_t \beta_t}{y_t - u_t}$, but that also does not comport with convention. If your aim is to communicate, notational convention helps. Just sayin'.

Comment: Ok you are right, thanks for the thoughtful comment!!! I will edit the question!!!!

Comment: I’m afraid the problem is not the time of your answer but the fact that I don’t recognize the equations

Comment: The equations don't work because, without any additional specifications, they imply the $\nu_t$ are *independent* and *identically distributed.* That is not possible for bounded $\beta_t$ unless the $\nu_t$ are identically zero.  What are you trying to model?

Comment: @whuber Thanks for the answer. In my model both $\nu_t$ and $u_t$ are assumed to be i.i.d Gaussian (I edited the question).

Comment: The problem remains: when the $v_t$ and $u_t$ are *iid* Gaussian, you cannot guarantee the $\beta_t$ will remain in $[-1,1]$ (or even remain bounded).  Indeed, it is *certain* that eventually they will move outside any predetermined bounds.

Comment: Ok thanks @whuber , this is the answer I was looking for. The fact is that my coefficient $\beta_t$ is bounded between -1 and 1 and I expect it to be persistent. Hence, in order to specify a dynamics for it without estimating another parameter I was wondering if I could model it as RW. I think I have to model it as a stationary  AR(1).

Comment: You have many options.  Use the theoretical knowledge of the system you are modeling to suggest appropriate statistical formulations.